# how to change the default size of a quick look in finder?

Tags: finder, quicklook

I use the quick look option (by pressing `space` when highlight a file in finder).
The quick look opens a preview of the file.
I would like to enlarge the size of this preview window. How can I do that?

Comment: What version of macOS is running on your Mac?

Comment: I have one Mac with Catalina and with Mojave.